# Shopify Liquid. If todays month equals

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm looking to change up some html content within an email using liquid to find the current month of the year and display said HTML content for each month.

If month equals August then diplay...

If month equals September then display...

If anyone could help on how to get that written up I'd be very greatful

I have got DotDigital to output the current month using it's date formatting

{{ account.datetime | date: "%B" }} but I then get lost on how to use that output for the custom content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
{% assign month = account.datetime | date: "%B" %}

{% case month %}
{% when 'January' %}
    Do something
{% when 'February' %}
    Do something
{% else %}
    If not January or February do something 
{% endcase %}
```